# Count number of times a PHP class is created

Tags: php, oop

I've got a php class that I create several instances for. I'd like to get a count of how many times I've created that object.

```
<?php
     class myObject {
         //do stuff
     }

    $object1 = new myObject;
    $object2 = new myObject;
    $object3 = new myObject;
?>
```

Is there a way to find that I've created 3 myObjects?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can create a [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) counter and increment it each time your [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) is called.

```
<?php
class BaseClass {
    public static $counter = 0;

    function __construct() {
        self::$counter++;
    }
}

new BaseClass();
new BaseClass();
new BaseClass();

echo BaseClass::$counter;
?>
```

Comment: if you also want to take cloned and unserialized instances into account, add the magic `__clone` and `__wakeup` methods and increment the counter in them as well.

Comment: To maintain accessibility, I've changed the mixed use of "static" and "self" to simply stick to "static", however, it's equally valid to stick to "self" for both uses.

Comment: This can be updated without object creation by using:
     BaseClass::$counter;

Can we restrict this outside updation?

Answer (score 3):

If your class has a __construct() function defined, it will be run every time an instance is created. You could have that function increment a class variable.