# Access main class from another PHP class

Tags: php

Good morning, I have to do the following exercise, and I have a couple of questions:

To create the vehicles, I would have to do it in the main class, how can I know from the vehicle class with the getVehiclesCreatives () method how many vehicles have I created?

When using the method go with the vehicle1 let's say "100km" How can it be added to the mileage of the vehicle1?

Thank you very much

**Create a Vehicle class that has the class methods getVehiclesCreated () and getKmTotals (); as well as the method of getKmRecorridos (). Test the class through an application that performs, at least, the following actions:
 - Create 3 vehicles
 - Go with the vehicle 1
 - Go with the vehicle 2
 - Go with the vehicle 3
 - View vehicle mileage1
 - View vehicle mileage2
 - View vehicle mileage3
 - View total vehicle mileage**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include ("./vehiculo.php");

    $vehiculo1 = new vehiculo();
    $vehiculo2 = new vehiculo();
    $vehiculo3 = new vehiculo();

    $vehiculo1 ->andar(100);
    $vehiculo1 ->getKmRecorridos();




?>
```

Class vehiculo

```
<?php

class vehiculo {

public static $vehiculosCreados = 0;
public static $kmTotales;
public $kmRecorridos;

function getVehiculosCreados() {
    return $this->vehiculosCreados;
}

function getKmTotales() {
    return $this->kmTotales;
}

function getKmRecorridos() {
    return $this->kmRecorridos;
}

function setVehiculosCreados($vehiculosCreados) {
    $this->vehiculosCreados = $vehiculosCreados;
}

function setKmTotales($kmTotales) {
    $this->kmTotales = $kmTotales;
}

function setKmRecorridos($kmRecorridos) {
    $this->kmRecorridos = $kmRecorridos;
    static $kmTotales;
    $this->kmTotales = $kmRecorridos + $kmTotales;
}

function andar($kms) {

    $kmRecorridos = $kms + $kmRecorridos;
}

function crearVehiculo($vehiculosCreados) {
    $this->$vehiculosCreados++;
}
```

}

Comment: You put code where it does not belong and you miss code which should be there. `static $kmTotales;` in function is not correct. In `andar($kms)` you forgot `$this->` before `$kmRecordiso`.... You should use a proper IDE that would highlight all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the number of instances of your class you need to do two things:

- In your class's `__construct` method increment your
  `vehiculosCreados` property while referencing `self` instead of
  `this`.
- Create a static function that returns the `vehiculosCreados`
  property that also references `self` instead of `this`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893212/count-number-of-times-a-php-class-is-created) question/answer for more info.

```
class vehiculo {

  public static $vehiculosCreados = 0;
  public static $kmTotales;
  public $kmRecorridos;

  public function __construct() {
    self::$vehiculosCreados++;
  }

  function getVehiculosCreados() {
   return self::$vehiculosCreados;
  }

  ..

}
```

And you can get the total instances of your class with `vehiculo::getVehiculosCreados()`

As for adding to the distance you've traveled you seem to have two variables, one to track the specific car's distance and another to track all car's distances? To increment both we can do it in the same function:

```
public function andar($kms) {
  $this->kmRecorridos += $kms;
  self::$kmTotales += $this->kmRecorridos;
}
```

And you can access the total with `vehiculo::$kmTotales` and the specific car's distance with `$vehiculo->getKmRecorridos()`.

`self::$kmTotales` will track all of your instances of `vehiculo`'s distance while `kmRecorridos` will track only the current object's traveled distance. I may be misunderstanding what you want, though, so let me know if it is!

Comment: Everything perfectly understood, thank you very much friend

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of classes you instantiated, you should have a shared variable between all of them. You can do this by declaring `$vehiculosCreados` as a static variable. Then you simply need to increment this variable in the constructor of your class.

To update the number of traveled kilometers, you need to increment the value of `$kmRecorridos` by `$kms`. You inverted the variables in your function `andar`, it should be `$kmRecorridos += $kms`.

To have the total number of traveled kilometers, you will need to declare `$kmTotales` as a static variable too!

Comment: I have modified what you have told me but I think I still do something wrong but I can not locate the error.

Comment: What problem do you encounter?

Comment: For example, when doing $ vehiculo1-> getKmRecorridos (); I get an errorNotice: Undefined variable: kmRecorridos in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicio2\vehiculo.php on line 37